# Mysqli returns case insensitive matches by default

Tags: mysql

I have a weird problem with Mysqli returning case insensitive matches. While doing query "TAUNO", it returns row with user name "Tauno". While doing query for "TaunO" it returns id for "Tauno" while "TaunO" is user with higher id.

```
                $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?";
                if ($n = $this->mysqli->prepare($query)) {
                    $n -> bind_param('s',$this->recipient);
                    $n -> execute();
                    $n -> bind_result($uid);
                    $n -> fetch();
                    $n -> close();
                }
```

I am using xampp if that matters and the user table has "latin1_swedish_ci" coding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change collate of the column to binary that needs to match, check this link:

[MySQL DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

You can also add **BINARY** keyword before column name as:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE BINARY username= 'TAUNO';
```